# Disable USB device when Mac sleeps

Tags: macos, usb, sleep-wake

I'm looking for a way to disable an USB device whenever my MacBook wants to go to sleep.

I'm aware that OS X controls power management for most devices fairly well, but in this case, which is an USB powered notebook cooler where I place the Mac on top of, the fans will not turn off unless I unplug the USB cable.

Is there a way to force Mac OS X to disable a specific hardware USB device (and hopefully reconnected) on sleep using Automator or something else?

Thank you in advance

PS: I'm aware of another question which is similar but the answer points to Hibernation as the solution - I'm not looking for that as a solution:
[How do I shut off a USB fan automatically when the Mac goes to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157826/how-do-i-shut-off-a-usb-fan-automatically-when-the-mac-goes-to-sleep)

Comment: why do you dot not want the proposed solution? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157826/how-do-i-shut-off-a-usb-fan-automatically-when-the-mac-goes-to-sleep

Comment: In order to do that your system needs to know the UUID of the device connected, or some form of Identification. Can you see any of those?

Comment: Hi, hibernation adds too much time to the process of picking up after where I left earlier. But good call on the UUID - the device apparently just pulls power and registar in no form whatsoever. Could I kill the hub where it's connected?   `+-o XHCI Root Hub USB 2.0 Simulation@0  <class IOUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x10001093c, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (6 ms), retain 15>`

Comment: did you use ioreg -p IOUSB to get the info ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: check this out for some ideas http://superuser.com/a/114763