# Disconnect removable media from power

Tags: macos, big-sur, microphone, pmset

I connected peripherals to my Mac via USB. When I put my Mac to sleep, the external microphone, for example, is still supplied with power.

Is there any way that once the Mac goes to sleep, that it will remove power from attached devices?

My idea was to use **Hibernatemode 25** and that's what I did in the end.  The `pmset` manpage states **that the RAM will be disconnected from the power**.  This means that there is absolutely no possibility that the system will wake up in the idle state and start charging.  Why can't Hibernatemode 25 work **and** how can I turn off the power when the Mac is in sleep mode?

Comment: Some devices don't react well to suddenly losing power. External drives, for example.

Comment: Look at this question. Does this helps? [https://apple.stackexchange.com/](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157826/how-do-i-shut-off-a-usb-fan-automatically-when-the-mac-goes-to-sleep)

Comment: I already have "hibernatemode 25".  “Hibernatemode 1” is suggested in the answers.  However, there are only 0, 3 and 25

Comment: I hope my answer is wrong and I know one thing. People love to show someone else they’re wrong on the internet, and I love it too since that’s how I learn...

Comment: @bmike I hope your answer is correct because I would like to give you the reputation points as a gift.  I find your attitude and knowledge very impressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I have seen. Apple designs the USB / Thunderbolt ports to support wake from sleep so the firmware has them always active by design. Same for providing charging of an accessory from the Mac battery or power supply.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-your-mac-resources-when-its-in-sleep-mh27905/mac